# Build table from two different array results mixing values

Tags: php, algorithm

I have this two arrays:

```
$pax = [
 'person1',
 'person2
];

$prices = [
 [
   'price1' => 100,
   'price2' => 200,
   'price3' => 300
 ],
 [
   'price1' => 100,
   'price2' => 200,
   'price3' => 300
 ]
];
```

I want to create a table like this from the previous values:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>person1</th>
    <th>person2</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>price1</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>price2</td>
    <td>$200</td>
    <td>$200</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>price3</td>
    <td>$300</td>
    <td>$300</td>
    <td>$600</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I can't get it to work with this code:

```
$pax    = ['person1', 'person2'];
$prices = [
    [
        'price1' => 100,
        'price2' => 200,
        'price3' => 300
    ],
    [
        'price1' => 100,
        'price2' => 200,
        'price3' => 300
    ]
];

$table = '<table width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Price Key</th>';
foreach ($pax as $person) {
    $table .= "<th>$person</th>";
}
$table .= '<th>Total</th></thead><tbody>';

foreach ($pax as $idx => $person) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($prices[$idx] as $key => $value) {
        $table .= "<td>$key</td>";
        $table .= "<td>$value</td>";
        $table .= '<td>Total</td>';
    }
    $table .= '<tr>';
}

$table .= '</tbody></table>';
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Why you don't show column for `price3`?

Comment: it's the sum of price1 and price2

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I am not sure what are you trying to say, could you explain yourself?

Comment: @Ivan yes that's it

Comment: @ReynierPM Everything all right. I thing you have one more price.

Comment: How about storing the key of prices into an array. Then, in the loop add a condition like `! in_array($key, $storedKeys)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is inside out. Each row is for a different `priceX`, but you have a row for each element of the `$pax` array.

You also need to calculate the totals.

```
if (!empty($prices)) { // So we don't try to access $prices[0] on empty array
    foreach (array_keys($prices[0]) as $key) {
        echo "<td>$key</td>";
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($prices as $person) {
            $total += $person[$key];
            echo "<td>\${$person[$key]}</td>";
        }
        echo "<td>\$$total</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `$pax[0]` only?

Comment: All the people have the same `priceX` keys, so `array_keys($pax[0])` is the same as `array_keys($pax[1])` and so on.

Comment: Oops, I see, I got `$pax` and `$prices` mixed up. It should be `$prices[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. But you have some issues in your second `for` loop.

Try this:

```
foreach (array_keys($prices[0]) as $key) {
        echo "<td>$key</td>";
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($prices as $price) {
            echo "<td>\${$price[$key]}</td>";
            $total += $price[$key];
        }
        echo "<td>\$$total</td>";
    }
```